# Place down arrow inside of input that's inside of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have multiple tables across my application. (plain html, css etc, no framework except jQuery)

In some of the td's inside of those tables i have input fields. In some inputs i want to place a downwards pointing arrow, so that the user knows they can click on it to get a custom made dropdown list.

For a while now i've been using something in the line of the example shown below.

So, the user needs to see an input field inside of which on the right side there is a downwards facing arrow.
Also, the text that the user fills in the input field must not go underneath the arrow.

The issue is that the arrow has a fixed width of 20px and a height of 20px, but the input field needs to be as wide as the width of the td minus the width of the arrow (20 px). Setting the input's width to a percentage doesn't work because when the td varies in size, there will be a blank space in between the input and arrow.

CSS:

```
.col1{
    width: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.col2{
    width:300px;
    background-color: lightgrey
}


.col1 input{
    width: 100%;
}

.ArrowBox {
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}




.ArrowIcon {
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg); 
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td class="col1">
          <input type="text" value="" class="input1">
           <i class="ArrowDownBox">
              <i class="InputArrowDownIcon"></i>
           </i>
       </td>
  
        <td class="col2">Line 1, Column 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td  class="col1">
         <input type="text" value="" class="input2">
            <i class="ArrowDownBox">
               <i class="InputArrowDownIcon"></i>
             </i>
       </td>
   
       <td class="col2">Line 2, Column 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've put a simple example in a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/j6ocL702/

The colors used are for example purposes.

Can anyone help me with this? i'm at a loss and google isn't my friend with this atm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the input `padding-right: 20px;` that will stop users typing under the arrow if you position the input relative and the down arrow absolute with `right: 0`

You'll probably have to fiddle around to make sure default margin or padding isn't being picked up.

Comment: Thanks! Your comments gave me a push in the right direction. I've changed my way of thinking because of it. I was giving the td a width and was trying to get the input and down arrow elements to fit into the parent td and its width at all times. Now i've changed it to: wrap the input and the down arrow both into their own div and then give both divs float left and a fixed (non percentage) width. This works great!